# No such file or directory when trying to create .ssh keys

Tags: debian, jenkins, gitlab, ssh-keygen

When I attempt to create ssh keys on my Debian instance :

```
ssh-keygen -f /home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am getting the error : Saving key "/home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory

I am using root user and when I check permissions on the directory :

```
 ls -ld
```

I get

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 08:32 .
```

I have a number of questions :

1)What am I missing and why is the system not able to automatically create the .ssh directory specified ?

2)Do I need to create another user and switch from using root. I am not sure if the new user will inherit permissions on all packages I have so far since I have installed them with root user profile?

I intend to use the ssh keys for integration between Jenkins and Gitlab as outlined here [Jenkins_GitlabIntegration](https://faun.pub/quick-and-easy-ci-cd-with-gitlab-and-jenkins-ba7821032e9c)

In the example however the Jenkins instance and Gitlab instance are installed on d**ifferent servers** and yet for my setup they are installed on the **same Debian instance** and also my Gitlab repo is **public**.

I am unsure as to whether I still need the ssh key because Jenkins and Gitlab are running on same Debian instance eg would Jenkins still need ssh keys in order to checkout the code from Gitlab.

Comment: check permissions on .ssh directory & even on /home/serverkeys just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I magnaged to create a new certificate with:

```
 ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/keys/server_name/id_rsa -q -N ""
```

(no -y or -c flags)

Beware: -y flag is not a confirmation

Comment: Replacing my prior *`rsa`* with **`ed25519`**, for the **`-t` option**, solved me.  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` didn't exist prior, because prior attempt with rsa failed to make it (can also see related https://stackoverflow.com/a/77892346/1357094).

Answer (score 0):

The `-f key_file` switch by itself does not create new keys and will also not create a `.ssh` directory. The -f switch is also used to take an existing key_file as input, when used with other switches.  See [`man ssh-keygen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen)

You need to use the `-c` option and  `ssh-keygen`**`-c`**`-f /home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa` to create a new private key.

Comment: ssh-keygen -c -f /home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/serverkeys/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

Comment: same error still showing